# Is Geb(automation testing framework) a good acceptance testing framework?

Tags: testing, groovy, acceptance-testing, geb

Is Geb(automation testing framework)  a good acceptance testing framework?

Answer (score 8):

This question might cause very opinionated answers and so will I answer your question from my point of view and try to offer some explanations for my thoughts. To make things clear I am a fan of Geb since I stumbled over it and now I want to explain why:

**[Page Objects Pattern](http://geb.codehaus.org/manual/latest/intro.html#the_page_object_pattern)**
Geb supports the Page Objects Pattern in a very pragmatic way. You can define elements with an jQuery-like syntax and use inheritance on your Page Objects to create an easy to maintain abstraction layer.

**[jQuery Navigator Syntax](http://geb.codehaus.org/manual/latest/intro.html#the_jquery_ish_navigator_api)**
With the jQuery Navigator syntax implementing the abstraction layer for your webpage never was easier. And in my opinion writing tests should be as easy as possible to make them happen in the real world of deadlines and fixed budgets.

**[Good documentation](http://geb.codehaus.org/manual/latest/index.html)**
Geb has a well written documentation that makes it easy to get help on the framework and helped me in nearly all problems I had with the framework.

**[Integration with Testing Frameworks](http://geb.codehaus.org/manual/latest/integrations.html#integrations)**
The integration with the most common testing frameworks in the Java world is very good and for JUnit and Spock I did not find anything that hindered me to write good tests with Geb. It also integrates with Cucumber and EasyB.

Comment: Should add to that the clear structure of tests which, combined with Page Objects, Navigators and Geb's neat syntax make them very readable.

Comment: It supports Groovy language....the best of both the worlds..the power of high level language and simplicity and expressiveness of a dynamic language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The rest of this answer only serves to satisfy the mandatory 30 characters.